# Shared Pointer Collections and common methods

Tags: c++, subclass, shared-ptr, derived-class

I do quite a bit of c++(11) BUT i tend to keep to what i know.

I am working on a queue type mechanism and I have bumped into a problem that I am sure must be solvable.

I have:

Base Class:

```
BaseWorldCommand
```

Pointer Type

```
typedef shared_ptr<const BaseWorldCommand> ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer;
```

Queue:

```
concurrent_queue<ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer>
```

Now I have a controlling class that allows commands to be added to the queue. The problem is, I want to add many different derived classes to the queue. 
So far the only working method I have for doing this is:

```
void InCommand(const WorldCommandA p_Command) { m_CommandInQueue.push(ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer(new (decltype(p_Command))(p_Command))); }

void InCommand(const WorldCommandB p_Command) { m_CommandInQueue.push(ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer(new (decltype(p_Command))(p_Command))); }

...
```

etc

Now WorldCommandA and WorldCommandB are both sub classes of BaseWorldCommand.

The problem here is that I need to declare a method each time I have a new subclass.

Is there anyway I can create a common method for adding items into my queue without having to declare a new method each time.

Now I have attempted to solve this, but each time I end up with just a BaseWorldCommand class in the queue and not the subclass as required.

Thanks,

Comment: What about a template method?

Comment: I have never used them. If that would solve the problem then i can google it. Are you sure it would solve the problem?

Comment: Given an inheritance hierarchy, is there any reason not to leverage polymorphism here?

Comment: It depends on what "the problem" is. Do all the derived types have the same constructor parameters?

Comment: All the derived types have an empty constructor, They simply have different properties

Comment: Polymorphism, is basically what i am trying to achieve, The problem is maintaining the properties of the derived classes one they do into the collection while having a simple method that can be used to add them to the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a design error. Your `InCommand` functions do not take their arguments as shared pointers, which is why you have to copy the arguments to create objects which the newly-created shared pointers can then manage.

One of the problems with this approach is that your `BaseWorldCommand` has to be made copyable because of that, which is usually not a good idea for object-oriented classes (i.e. with virtual functions). If you want to go through with this, a better approach would be to add a virtual `Clone` function to `BaseWorldCommand`.

Or, what I'd consider the preferable approach, you could instead make your `InCommand` functions take `std::shared_ptr<InCommand>` and require clients to create the shared pointers (preferably by using `std::make_shared`). As it happens, the problem of multiple functions will then go away, because you will only need one such function.

```
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

class BaseWorldCommand
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseWorldCommand() {}
protected:
    BaseWorldCommand();
private:
    BaseWorldCommand(BaseWorldCommand const&) = delete;
    BaseWorldCommand& operator=(BaseWorldCommand const&) = delete;
};

struct WorldCommandA : BaseWorldCommand {};
struct WorldCommandB : BaseWorldCommand {};

using ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer = std::shared_ptr<BaseWorldCommand const>;

std::queue<ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer> queue;

void InCommand(ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer command)
{
    queue.push(command);
}

int main()
{
    InCommand(std::make_shared<WorldCommandA>());
    InCommand(std::make_shared<WorldCommandB>());
}
```

See also [GotW #91 Solution: Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) for a lenghty discussion and the following guideline:

> Express that a function will store and share ownership of a heap
>   object using a by-value `shared_ptr` parameter.

Comment: Using the ConstBaseWorldCommandPointer as a parameter was something I tried. But it makes it a bit annoying for the person calling the method. Ie each time having to convert the data type. I was hoping to black box this type change inside the method if possible.   Having said that, using the make_shared is not all that bad, and as i add more and more types that could be a better pattern to follow.

Comment: @PaulSpain: The point is, if you want to share a dynamically allocated object with `std::shared_ptr`, then you had best make the choice right at the point of creation. If the object had originally been created in some other way, then things inevitably get complicated.

Comment: I have now switched all my code to pass in make_shared<... The code now reads a lot better even through i do need to type a bit more code each time i call the queuing method.  Thanks.